# Does Python Base Exception Handling on Static or Dynamic Scoping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, theory

I've been trying to research more about Python 3 with regard to PL theory, specifically on exception handling. Does it follow static or dynamic scoping rules? I can't seem to find any resource answering these so I hope to find it here! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is simple enough to test. As with many static vs. dynamic problems, we simply need to set up a pair of functions to distinguish the behavior.

```
def foo():
    raise Exception("Static")

def bar():
    try:
        foo()
    except Exception:
        print("Dynamic")

bar()
```

If exception handling uses static scope, then there's no `except` block to catch our exception, so we'll see `"Static"` printed (along with a stack trace). If it's dynamic, then the `except` block in `bar` will catch the exception and we'll see `"Dynamic"` printed.

If we run this, we get `Dynamic`, so you have your answer.

On a more general note, exception handling is generally going to be dynamically scoped. Static scoping is nice for variables, because you get neat results like closures and more predictable semantics, but the whole point of exceptions is that you *don't* know who is going to handle the error. If you know how to handle it, you should handle it rather than throwing an exception. So philosophically it only makes sense to be dynamically typed, as you're passing responsibility to the caller.